# ¿Como puedo crear probabilidades?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Básicamente, estoy creando un comando de ruleta de colores (rojo, verde y negro) para un bot de casino y funciona de esta manera:

puedes apostar x cantidad a x color: !ruleta verde 500

y lo que quiero hacer es que el color negro y rojo tengan un 40% de probabilidades de que salgan mientras que el color verde solo tenga un 20% de probabilidades.

Hice el comando, pero todos los colores tienen las mismas probabilidades, esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora.

https://sourceb.in/lDIwA2l0Sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de lograrlo es multiplicar la cantidad de veces que existe una misma opción.

Por ejemplo, supongamos un arreglo con los tres colores.

```
// 3 opciones de 33.33% de probabilidad cada una
['rojo', 'negro', 'verde']
```

La probabilidad de que salga cualquiera es del `33.33%`.
En cambio si, por ejemplo, agregamos otra vez el `verde` al arreglo:

```
// 4 opciones de 25% de probabilidad cada una
['rojo', 'negro', 'verde', 'verde']
```

Ahora la probabilidad de que salga el *"rojo o negro"* es del `25%`, mientras que para el *"verde"* es del `50%`.

Usando este forma, para que la probabilidad de que salga *"rojo o negro"* sea del `40%` (*cada uno*) y de que salga *"verde"* del `20%`, podemos hacerlo así:

```js
// 5 opciones de 20% de probabilidad cada una
let colors = ['rojo', 'rojo', 'negro', 'negro', 'verde'];
let color = colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length))];
console.log(color);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! ^^